# How to show the last link in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am doing a project in cakephp. Here I need a different layout. Please have a look at my pagination requirements

```
<<First  <Prev  1|2|3|4|5|6  Next>  Last>>
```

There are 6 page items ,whenever I reached the page 6 , cake won't display the Last>> ,same case in First Button Button ,it hides that automatically.

However I need to keep the above layout for my pagination , If I click any link ,it should display the all links.

How Could I handle this? Is it possible?

Comment: Which version of cake are you using?

Comment: Do you need the link to be *clickable*, or do you just want it there because other elements will move if it's not? If the latter, you should simply fix that through CSS.

Comment: @deceze Yes I need links clickable. Can u show some samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think this will be helpfull for you

[Last Link In Cake PHP](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperlast)